# Rake dependency not executing but invoke works

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I've been trying to run `rake db:test:clone_structure`, but it keeps failing to rebuild the database. I finally looked at the task itself:

```
task :clone_structure => [ "db:structure:dump", "db:test:load_structure" ]
```

When I run the trace, I've noticed that `db:test:load_structure` isn't getting executed:

```
$ rake db:test:clone_structure --trace
** Invoke db:test:clone_structure (first_time)
** Invoke db:structure:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:structure:dump
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:clone_structure
```

Now, when I change the `clone_structure` task to *invoke* `load_structure`...

```
task :clone_structure => [ "db:structure:dump", "db:test:load_structure" ] do   
  db_namespace["test:load_structure"].invoke
end
```

...everything suddenly works!

```
$ rake db:test:prepare --trace

** Invoke db:test:clone_structure (first_time)
** Invoke db:structure:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:structure:dump
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:clone_structure
** Invoke db:test:load_structure (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge 
** Execute db:test:load_structure
** Invoke db:structure:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:structure:load
```

What could possibly be causing this behavior? I'm using Rails 3.2.14 and Rake 10.1.0.

**UPDATED:** I upgraded Rails to 3.2.13 from 3.2.11 and it's still a problem.

**UPDATED THE SECOND:** I upgraded Rails to 3.2.14 and Rake to 10.1.0 and it's still a problem

Comment: Does your structure.sql get created with no problems when you run 'rake db:test:clone_structure'? Do you see any issues with it?

Comment: Can you try running `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:test:prepare --trace`? I've sometimes seen that `RAILS_ENV` had to be set for certain tasks to get executed.

Comment: @yuri: db:test:clone_structure looks like it works perfectly. I'll throw some debugs in to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sticking a stack trace in one of the tasks I knew was being called, I found the problem. It has nothing to do with ActiveRecord or Rake and everything to do with the [activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced) gem, that I'm also using.

Basically, the gem overrides the `db:test:clone_structure` task like so:

```
redefine_task :clone_structure => [ "db:structure:dump", "db:test:purge" ]
```

Note that it misses any reference to `db:test:load_structure`.

I've submitted an [issue](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/326) and [pull request](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/327) to the project, so it should hopefully be resolved in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are almost there. As far as I know the [rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/Rake/Task.html) convention for this would be...

```
task :clone_structure => [ "db:structure:dump", "db:test:load_structure" ] do   
  Rake::Task["clone_structure"].invoke
end
```

Otherwise, I prefer...

```
task :clone_structure do   
  Rake::Task["db:structure:dump"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:test:load_structure"].invoke
end
```